# Cypress - have to use forEach loop with array returned by function in describe block

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, foreach, cypress

I have a function which returns array

```
 getOffersCategories() {
    cy.get(offersHeaders).then($els => {      
      cy.wrap(Cypress._.map(Cypress.$.makeArray($els), 'innerText')).as("categories")
    })
    return this;
  }
```

Now I need to call this function and use array with forEach block having multiple test cases (something like this)

```
offersCategories.forEach((item, index) => {
        it("Validate Max Carousels Limit, Left Right Swipe, See All link of " + item, function () 
        {
          ...
        }
})
```

For me it works fine if I array value is declared in same spec file Like `var offersCategories = ["a", "b",c"]` or fetched from fixtures, but not finding any way to use the same functionality when array details fetched from function.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: your `getOffersCategories` function does not return an array, it returns `this`. So it does nothing with the `cy.get(offersHeaders)` which you are computing in the function.

Comment: I believe you cannot use cy commands outside of tests/hooks.

Comment: Yeah right @jjhelguero but we cant even assign values at run time as global variable..